# Popping a list from a parent class attribute not working as intended

Tags: python

```
from random import choice

class PlayingCards:
    suits = ['Diamond','Club','Heart','Spade']
    numbers = [x for x in range(2,11)] + list('JQKA')
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_deck = [[number,suit] for number in self.numbers for suit in self.suits]
        self.drawed_card = []
        self.drawn_cards = []

    def hit(self):
        if self.main_deck:
            self.drawed_card = self.main_deck.pop(choice(range(len(self.main_deck))))
            self.drawn_cards.append(self.drawed_card)
            return self.drawed_card
        else:
            return None
    
class PlayerHand(PlayingCards):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player_drawn_cards = []

    def hit(self):
        if self.main_deck:
            self.drawed_card = self.main_deck.pop(choice(range(len(self.main_deck))))
            self.player_drawn_cards.append(self.drawed_card)
            return self.drawed_card
        else:
            return None

cards = PlayingCards()
player1_cards = PlayerHand()

cards.hit()
print(len(cards.main_deck))

player1_cards.hit()
print(len(cards.main_deck))
```

I'm trying to create a separate list which contains the card drawn by the player himself as well as the dealer which I will be adding further down this small project of mine.

When I ran the code above, the output for both `print(len(cards.main_deck))` and `print(len(cards.main_deck))` is 51. Shouldn't it be 50 since I called the `hit()` method twice?

Comment: `main_deck` isn't a class attribute: it's an instance attribute which is initialised to a new list in `__init__` each time an instance of the class is created. So `cards.main_deck` and `player1_cards.main_deck` are entirely independent lists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code's **init** method's structure causes each instance of PlayerHand and PlayingCards to generate a unique main_deck. This indicates that player1_cards and the main deck of cards are unrelated to one another.

The cards instance's main_deck is modified when cards.hit() is called, and its size is decreased to 51. But when you use player1_cards.hit(), it also reduces the size of the player1_cards instance's main_deck, which is a whole different deck, to 51. Because the second call has no effect on it, the length of cards.main_deck stays 51 after both calls.

You may either manage the deck externally and send it to the constructors of your classes, or you can make main_deck a class variable (shared across all instances) so that PlayingCards and PlayerHand instances have a shared deck.
from random import choice

```
class PlayingCards:
    suits = ['Diamond', 'Club', 'Heart', 'Spade']
    numbers = [x for x in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    main_deck = [[number, suit] for number in numbers for suit in suits]
    drawed_card = []
    drawn_cards = []

    @classmethod
    def hit(cls):
        if cls.main_deck:
            cls.drawed_card = cls.main_deck.pop(choice(range(len(cls.main_deck))))
            cls.drawn_cards.append(cls.drawed_card)
            return cls.drawed_card
        else:
            return None
    
class PlayerHand(PlayingCards):

    def __init__(self):
        #super().__init__()
        self.player_drawn_cards = []
    # def hit(self):
    #     if self.main_deck:
    #         self.drawed_card = self.main_deck.pop(choice(range(len(self.main_deck))))
    #         self.player_drawn_cards.append(self.drawed_card)
    #         return self.drawed_card
    #     else:
    #         return None

    def hit(self):
        card = super().hit()
        if card:
            self.player_drawn_cards.append(card)
        return card

cards = PlayingCards()
player1_cards = PlayerHand()

cards.hit()
print(len(PlayingCards.main_deck))  # Should print 51

player1_cards.hit()
print(len(PlayingCards.main_deck))  # Should print 50 now
```

Comment: Sorry for the earlier one. But mainly I was stating this.

Comment: Please be aware that answers generated by ChatGPT are not allowed on SO - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `main_deck` to be an instance attribute, which means a new `main_deck` is created each time `PlayingCards` is used. Each time you call `PlayingCards`, the `init` function creates a new `main_deck`, meaning there is no relation between `player1_cards.main_deck` and `cards.main_deck`.

You would need to pull from the same deck, instead of calling the `init` function that creates a separate deck, for the cards to total 50, and to successfully implement card removal for a real-world scenario.